# Are these equivalent?

Tags: c, recursion, quicksort, mergesort

In main function of `merge sort` and `quicksort` we use the following for recursion

```
mergesort(int * arr, int low, int high){

if(low<high){
        //mergesort();
        //mergesort();
        //merge();
    }
}
```

I however used an alternative to it, which is:

```
mergesort(int * arr, int low, int high){

if(low==high){
return;
} 
//mergesort();
//mergesort();
//merge();

}
```

I believe whenever low will be equal to high then the recursion will stop. And will start performing the work from previous calls.
But it didnot work so!
Any idea why?

Comment: Why don't you just run your program in a debugger and have a look at the `low` and `high` values? The answer should become evident fairly quickly when you do that.

Comment: Show arguments to the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

In your first portion of code if block works only when low is less than high. So if you want to rewrite the checking you need to ensure that whenever low is equal or greater than high your function should stop recursive calls.

Try checking like this.

```
if(low>=high){   //you have to check if low becomes greater or equal to high too!
    return;
}
```